# Offset Lat Lon coordinate by some meter in driving direction and to side

Tags: c++, geocoding

I would like to offset a coordinate (Lat/Lon) by a small amount of meters ( 1 - 2 meters ) to the back of a driving vehicle and to the right.

It has to be really exact!

I found a function that seems to work, but is not accurate (or wrong?):

```
double deltaSide = 1.0; // +=offset to the right
double deltaRear = 1.1; // +=offset in backwards-direction of driving

//transform to offset to North and East
double deltaSideN = -deltaSide * sin( m_yaw_d ) - deltaRear * cos( m_yaw_d );
double deltaSideE = deltaSide * cos( m_yaw_d ) - deltaRear * sin( m_yaw_d );

f_lat_d = f_orgLat_d + deltaSideN / (double)EARTH_RADIUS * rad2grad;
f_lon_d = f_orgLon_d + deltaSideE / (double)EARTH_RADIUS / cos( f_orgLat_d * grad2rad ) * rad2grad;
```

Is there a more accurate function to do so? Or do I just make a major mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm perplexed by the radians to gradians conversion. Latitude/longitude are in degrees, no?

Comment: How many bits accurate? You're using `EARTH_RADIUS` which suggests you're not actually caring that much. Earth isn't a sphere.

Comment: @john: Latitude and longitude are angles, so they can be in anything.

Comment: @MSalters Sure, but in normal usage there are in degrees. Gradians seems an odd choice.

Comment: If the suffix _d means degree, then m_yaw_d must be converted to radians before sin/cos can be applied.